# TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, tns

I am very new to this
I install oracle in Linux machine with orcl service
And created one mmsc user. If I am not login with mmsc user and try to connect sqlplus with the command, "sqlplus mmsc/mmsc" and "sqlplus mmsc/mmsc@orcl" Then listener is working for both the option.

But after login to mmsc user, 
listener is working for "sqlplus mmsc/mmsc" but not working for "sqlplus mmsc/mmsc@orcl".

Please help me to solve this issue.

Thanks in Advance

Regards
Sankar

Comment: `not working` is not helpful at all, please provide error message. Also, what do you mean by `after login`? So first you connect using *sqlplus*, see the message `connected to instance` (or similar) and then issue the command `sqlplus mmsc/mmsc` under *sqlplus* session?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the client does not find the tnsnames.ora file. The file is generally located in the directory $ORACLE_HOME/network/admin. To find the file it is the best to set the environment variable TNS_ADMIN to point to that directory. This of course requires that the mmsc user has read permissions in that directory.